# move the buttons and text below using css

Tags: html, css

please visit [link1](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/chhota-bheem-jaggu-keychain.html) , here everything is fine.

[image]

please visit [link2](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/ship.html)

here, 1)i want to move "Add to cart" and " buy now" buttton bit below.

also I want to display the text "Selling Price (Free Delivery )" below "RS 50".

I want to display link2 as like link1.

[image]

we are using following code :

```
.product-ship .sell_price {
    color: #848484;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
    top: -130px;
}

product-view .add-to-cart button.button span {
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add top margin to `.product-options-bottom`

```
.product-options-bottom {
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 45px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: some line is displaying between RS 50 and  "Selling Price (Free Delivery )"

Comment: please help me here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37545936/display-background-color-for-the-page-align-texts-at-center

Answer (score 2):

your define `height: 75px;` in your `.price-box` please it's change into this

`.product-view .product-essential .product-shop .price-box{height:auto;}`

Comment: its displaying too much gap between Add to cart and RS 50

Comment: make height: 80px; in your .price-box

Comment: glad you found a solution :)

Answer (score 1):

display table and height auto solution of you problem

```
.product-view .product-essential .product-shop .price-box
{
 display:table;
 height:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Never use the auto value until and unless it is mandatory, otherwise it will take the default height corresponding to the the height value that has been set to that particular division.

Better to give height in pixel(px) as this is dynamic value and can be fitted to any of the screen size.

In order to move  you can use 
 tag 2 times.

I think this issue is due to missing of 
 tag. Just try to place 
 tag at after these two button to bring "Buy now" button at the end of the both button.
Same thing is applicable to your test "Selling Price."

Just try and let me know, if the issue persist.
Overall your code is correct.

Comment: I mentioned [<br>] tag in the solution, but it is not getting reflected there. So, try to use [<br>] tag